# Writing python tests for unauthorized users of AWS services

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-codebuild

I'm writing python tests to make sure Amazon S3 (the service in general) works as intended.

The setup: CodePipeline uses CodeBuild to create an S3 bucket using a CloudFormation template, then it kicks off another CodeBuild job to run the python tests against the S3 created in the previous step.

I need to write tests for these two requirements:

> "Unauthorized users shall receive a 403 response when attempting to modify an S3 bucket."

and

> "Authorized users shall be able to successfully access and modify an S3 bucket."

The second test isn't an issue, but I'm not sure how to write the first test.

My question is: how can I get the python test to test the S3 bucket *as an unauthorized user*?  CodeBuild already has permissions to access the S3 buckets, so I'm not sure how to make the tests (which are run with CodeBuild) to NOT have permission to access them and get the 403 I need.

Here's some more detail, for those would would find it helpful:

The pipeline has 4 phases: source, build, deploy, buildtest, and delete.  The deploy stage is where the S3 buckets I need to test are being stood up using a CloudFormation stack.  The buildtest phase is where I'm actually running these python tests, so that's where I imagine I'll need to implement a solution to this problem.

Eventually, this whole process will be initiated with a CloudFormation template that MAKES a pipeline, which will have all these phases.  But for right now, it's just using the pipeline from the AWS Console.  I only mention this in case something is possible (or not possible) from CloudFormation to make this work, that may(not) be available in CodeBuild.

Unfortunately, I don't have much python code I can share here, since this is the first test I need to write, and I have no idea how to approach it.  But what I can tell you is that I'm using Boto3 and running the tests using unittest.  I'm finding the buckets by inspecting the current stacks in CloudFormation, and seeing which one matches the test stack name, then grabbing the S3 resource from that stack.  That's the bucket I'm testing.  So somehow, I need to see that bucket, try to access it, and get denied for one test, then get access in the other test.

```
#python 3.6
import os
import boto3
import unittest

rootstack = os.getenv('RootStackName')   # environment variable in the build
region = 'us-west-2'
buckets = {}

class TestS3(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):    
      self.customBucket = None

      self.customBucket = buckets['customBucket']

      if self.customBucket is None:
        raise ValueError('Test bucket not found in test setUp!')

    def test_bucket_accessible_if_authorized(self):
      # Authorized user can access the bucket
      self.assertEqual(????)

    def test_bucket_cant_be_accessed_if_unauthorized(self):
      # Unauthorized user CANNOT access the bucket
      self.assertEqual(????)


if __name__=='__main__':
  try:
    cfn = boto3.client('cloudformation', region_name=region)
    response = cfn.describe_stack_resources(StackName=rootstack)
    resources = response['StackResources']

    for resource in resources:
      if resource['ResourceType'] == 'AWS::S3::Bucket':
        print('FOUND THE CUSTOM BUCKET')
        buckets['customBucket'] = resource

    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
  except Exception as e:
    print("Unknown Error, %s" %(e))
```

Comment: Can't you create another connection and override the credentials with another set that doesn't have access to your S3 ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by create another connection.  is this something I'd write in the Python, or a configuration in CodeBuild somewhere?

Comment: You're talking about Python tests accessing AWS S3. Those tests are probably using boto3 and you're just initializing the client with the default credentials from your environment. You can, however, force specific credentials in this client init. You could have one with the default credentials and another with specific ones. Since there isn't much detail in your question, especially no code, we can't be much more specific.

Comment: You are correct in that I'm using boto3, but I'm not executing these tests locally.  This is all taking place in CodeBuild, which uses the permissions granted to it with its IAM role.  Hm, perhaps I should just make another phase of the pipeline, one that gives that second Project in CodeBuild a different role.  That seems like kind of a clunkly solution though - two totally different phases of the pipeline, just to get around this issue.  I'll post some code that seems relevant, but let me know if it would be more useful to see something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up taking the approach of just modifying the credentials in the code before attempting to access the S3 buckets and objects.  If I got AccessDenied, then that confirms the security is working as intended.

For example:

```
def test_unauthorized_read(self):
    # unauthorized users will 'Access Denied' if attempting to list the S3 bucket
    cantListBuckets = False
    # the user assigned in the next line has NO permissions to access any service
    client = boto3.client(service_name='s3',
        aws_access_key_id='AKIBI6SPIAUZ6LTGA4BQ',
        aws_secret_access_key='HyqAJOXgqt6kCOSay/2eH6J3FYcbwjNTjTyhtHOQ'
    )
    try:
        buckets = client.list_buckets()
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        if 'AccessDenied' in str(e):
            cantListBuckets = True

    self.assertTrue(cantListBuckets)
```

Not ideal... feel free to post any better approaches.

Comment: not a good idea to leave the key's in the post